# Wrong regular expression for mapper

Tags: java, regex, youtube-api

This is my code in my mapper.

```
 result.put("contentThumbUrl", getThumbUrl(extractor.extract("youtube.videolink").asText(), false));
            result.put("contentThumbSmallUrl", getThumbUrl(extractor.extract("youtube.videolink").asText(), true));
```

My function is :

```
private String getThumbUrl(String videoId, boolean small) {
        videoId = videoId.replaceAll("http://www\\.youtube\\.([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{3})/watch\\?v=.|https://www\\.youtube\\.([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{3})/watch\\?v=", "");
        if(small) {
            return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/2.jpg";
        }
        return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg";
    }
```

However i got the false result.

```
"contentThumbSmallUrl":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=lEBwKBJ8Leg\/2.jpg"
and 
contentThumbUrl":"http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=lEBwKBJ8Leg\/0.jpg"
```

Is there anyway I can correct it. I don't know if my regular expression is correct. Is there any way I can shorten my regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it fails on that text. It looks strange though, with the escaped slashes (`\/`). Only backslashes (`\`) should need to be escaped. You should check your input.

The only problem with the regex I can see, is an extraneous period (`.`) after the first half: `\\?v=.|https://`. It would remove an extra character from the video id.

To shorten the pattern, you could do this:

```
"http(s)?://www\\.youtube\\.([a-z]{2,3})/watch\\?v="
```

The parenthesis are optional, but aids readability.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/9gRG8Q/1